# populate and read an array with a list of filenames

Tags: arrays, bash, populate

Trivial question.

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -z "$1"
then
  echo "No args!"
  exit
fi

for newname in $(cat $1); do
  echo $newname
done
```

I want to replace that echo inside the loop with **array population** code.
Then, after the loop ends, I want to **read the array** again and echo the contents.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file, as your code shows, has a set of files, each in one line, you can assign the value to the array as follows:

```
array=(`cat $1`)
```

After that, to process every element you can do something like:

```
for i in ${array[@]} ; do echo "file = $i" ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -a files
while IFS= read -r
do
    files+=("$REPLY") # Array append
done < "$1"
echo "${files[*]}" # Print entire array separated by spaces
```

[`cat` is not needed](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( )
for f in $(cat $1); do
    files[${#files[*]}]=$f
done

for f in ${files[@]}; do
    echo "file = $f"
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work: only the last element of the array been saved.

Comment: strange, I did it on my machine just with `ls -1` instead of `cat $1` and it was working... maybe bash version related!?

Comment: You need to add double quotes: `for f in "${files[@]}"`

Comment: you can append to an array (in bash) with: `files+=($f)`